# Drop a table originally created with 'unknown tokenizer'?

Tags: sqlite, tokenize, fts4

I have a sqlite3 database. A single table inside this DB can't be dropped, the error message says `unknown tokenizer: mm`.

I tried it directly with the command `DROP TABLE tablename;` inside the newest [SQLiteSpy](http://www.yunqa.de/delphi/products/sqlitespy/index) v1.9.11 and also within .NET code and the official sqlite [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Data.SQLite) package v 1.0.103.

How can I drop a table where the tokenizer is unknown?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/fts3.html#shadow_tables) says:

> For each FTS virtual table in a database, three to five real (non-virtual) tables are created to store the underlying data. These real tables are called "shadow tables". The real tables are named "%_content", "%_segdir", "%_segments", "%_stat", and "%_docsize", where "%" is replaced by the name of the FTS virtual table.

So to get rid of that table, drop the shadow tables:

```
DROP TABLE tablename_content;
DROP TABLE tablename_segdir;
DROP TABLE tablename_segments;
DROP TABLE tablename_stat;
DROP TABLE tablename_docsize;
```

And then use the (very dangerous) [PRAGMA writable_schema](http://www.sqlite.org/pragma.html#pragma_writable_schema) to remove the remaining information about this table from the system table:

```
PRAGMA writable_schema = ON;
DELETE FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'tablename';
```

SQLite caches schema information, so then you need to close and re-open the database.