# Corrupted Database Table cannot DROP

Tags: sqlite, fts4

Using SQLite3 and Ubuntu 14.04-LTS. I managed to mis-type when creating a Virtual table for a FTS search. Now I cannot remove the Table. This is what I wanted:

```
CREATE VIRTUAL TABLE tFind USING FTS4(main TEXT, base TEXT, hash TEXT);
```

But, I must have hit "5" instead of "4" and now I can't `DROP` the table. When I try I get this error:

> Error refreshing schema for table main.tFind : No such module FTS5

I searched and found information on SQLite3 for the Terminal (CLI), but I do not know how to use the commands within.

How can I repair this? I have many hundreds of rows of data and a dozen or so tables, so I cannot just create a new database with the same tables.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved: Found th following "

[Drop a table originally created with 'unknown tokenizer'?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40877078/drop-a-table-originally-created-with-unknown-tokenizer?rq=1)

Where the

> And then use the (very dangerous) PRAGMA writable_schema to remove the
>   remaining information about this table from the system table:

```
PRAGMA writable_schema = ON;
DELETE FROM sqlite_master WHERE type = 'table' AND name = 'tFind';
```

Many thanks to CL. for that Post.